# Trying to set titleView for navigationItem works on simulator but not on actual device

Tags: image, set, navigationitem, titleview

I'm trying to set a titleView in the NavigationBar using the following code. It shows correctly on the simulator but it doesn't on the device.

This is my code:

```
UIImage *imageTitle = [UIImage imageNamed: @"tittle_SW.png"];
UIImageView *imageViewForTitle = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: imageTitle];

self.navigationItem.titleView = imageViewForTitle;
self.navigationItem.titleView.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
```

I tried using this code in initWithNibName and viewDidLoad, and well, both work on the simulator but it doesn't show anything on the device.